# Setting data by using innerHTML can't bring data with querySelector

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, queryselector

```
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = `
  <i class="fa fa-square-o item btn emptyButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-check-square-o item btn checkedButton dis-non" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span class='item' id = '${anArray.length + 1}'>${INPUTVALUE}</span>
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o btn removeButton item" aria-hidden="true"></i>
`;
```

I was setting HTML data like above, then I was having trouble with getting data.
I wanted to use `querySelector` like following with span and its id:

```
document.querySelector('span#2')
```

But I could not get anything so I had to do crazy work like:

```
ET.arentElement.arentElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerText;
```

This is not from the example code, but because this is the worst so I wanted to use this as an example.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: @Crowder Thank you for the tip! I am going to read everything :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [ID cannot start with a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Use something like:

```
document.querySelector('#my-data-2')
```

and your span:

```
<span class='item' id ='my-data-${anArray.length + 1}'>
```

(all inside the back tick, as in your code).

Comment: The `span` has an `id` which is presumably 2 in this particular case. Also note that it seems likely there are other spans in the document. *(not my dv)*

Comment: oh I thought she had the mis-concept of `span#2` being the second one

Comment: Thank you. I got an idea from your answer, and I solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

`span#2` is an invalid CSS selector, ID selectors can't start with unescaped digits (more in [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)). In general, you're best off not using ID values that start with digits, but if you do, you have to select them differently — either by not using a CSS selector:

```
span = document.getElementById("2");
```

...or by escaping it (but frankly that's a bit ugly), or using the attribute form:

```
span = document.querySelector("[id='2']");
```

---

Note also [Scott Marcus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59936831/157247) — if your code wasn't appending the `li` to the document before trying to get the element, you'd either want to append it to the document, or use `querySelector` on `li`:

```
span = li.querySelector("[id='2']");
```

---

In the CSS selector, as Taplar pointed out in a comment, in this particular case since the `span` has a class, you can add the class:

```
span = document.querySelector("[id='2'].item");
// or
span = li.querySelector("[id='2'].item");
```

Comment: I should have read 'How do I ask a good question?' before I ask. You are giving me full of information but I gave you not enough info. I'm sorry. I already did append child. And `document.querySelector("[id=2].item");` says it is not a valid selector. I gave id with numbers because I was comparing with other elements id if it is equal. I should change my whole code or organize my question again. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @SophiaLee - Sorry about that, you need quotes around the `2` for the same reason it's not valid in `#2`. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `document.createElement()`, then the new element exists in memory, but is not automatically inserted into the current DOM. You need to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or [insert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) it into the DOM and then you will be able to locate it.

With `.innerHTML` the HTML string is parsed into the DOM immediately so you don't need to formally append or insert an element created that way. This is why, in the code below, only the `li` variable needs to be appended and all the `.innerHTML` of that element does not.

```js
let anArray = [];
let INPUTVALUE = "test";

const li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-square-o item btn emptyButton" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-check-square-o item btn checkedButton dis-non" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span class='item' id = '${anArray.length + 1}'>${INPUTVALUE}</span>
<i class="fa fa-trash-o btn removeButton item" aria-hidden="true"></i>`;

// You must append/insert the dynamically created element into the DOM
document.body.appendChild(li);

// Then, you can find it:
console.log(document.querySelector("span.item").textContent);
```